# DIV as filling block in another DIV

Tags: html, css

I have a CSS

```
.nav {
    width: 200px;
    line-height: 50px;
    float: left;
}
.content {
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 230px;
}
.container {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

And here is the HTML

```
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="nav">Some text
        <br>more text
        <br>even more text
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <h1>Home</h1>
        <p>Text paragraph</p>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

This gives me menu on the left and the content on the right. And a red box around the content on the right, but only the half menu on the left.

But I would like to have the red box also around the complete nav-div Can anyone help?

Thanks
Teddy

Comment: @Gunaseelan I just formatted his code.... It was reviewed by mods so what's the problem? Code like `<a href="#">hegbzgdiez</a>` doesn't mean a lot does it? So I changed his "ziugiuzu" to real words...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `overflow:auto` to your container div's CSS:

```
.container {
    border: 1px solid red;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/LLs8u8dw/)**

Floating the child div removes it from the flow of the document and the container essentially collapses as if it didn't exist. Adding the overflow restores the behavior you're after.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a quick fix if you float your container it should solve the problem your having. See here http://jsfiddle.net/1540sscj/

```
.container {
    border: 1px solid red;
    float:left;
    width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way imho would be to add a div like:

```
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

Under your floating elements:  **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/alvaromenendez/5k9r9cbn/)**

This way you don't need to use `oveflow:hidden` on your container that may give you problems once you have more stuff in your project.

Also you shoudn't use a margin-left for your content as the previous element is already floating left. The best practise if you want to add some margin between nav and content would be to make your content float left as well and then use margin left (the exact size you want) with respect of the nav and not with the left of the window.

Finally, if you don't want to add the `clear:both` div to the html you could add somethign like

```
.content:after {
    content:'';
    display:block;
    clear: both;
}
```

it's a bit less browser (old ones) compatible but cleaner

Comment: empty markup for styling purpose only is not a good idea, especially when solutions that don't need to insert new markup exist

Comment: That's why I have added the use of pseudoelements to get same effect. However I think it's much better to add the div in the html than the use of overflow:hidden. Anyway it's just my opinion and of course many people will agree with you. I don't (in this case)

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `overflow:auto` to `.container` in your css

Check my [js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uudmcotg/)

Also the css that modified.

```
.container {
    border: 1px solid red;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

Description of property [overflow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow) from MDN

> The overflow property specifies whether to clip content, render
>   scrollbars or just display content when it overflows its block level
>   container.

Comment: How's this different from my answer of 7 minutes ago?

Comment: @j08691 I have added the description about `overflow` property. And I haven't copied from your answer.

Comment: I didn't say you copied from my answer. But the answer, `add overflow:auto to .container in your css` is the same as mine. So why do we need a duplicate?

Comment: @j08691 There is a need to explain why we use `overflow` property to fix the issue. And the reference came from the well documented place Mozila Developer network

Comment: @Gunaseelan You could have edited his answer since your answer doesn't really add any value.

Answer (score 0):

Floating an element removes it from the normal flow of the page with one side effect being that its parent's dimensions won't expand to fit it.

So, what you need to do is `clear` the floated item. The best way to do this, without using additional markup or using the `overflow` property, which may cause other issues, depending on your layout, is to use the `:after` pseudo class on the parent element, like so:

```css
.nav{
    width:200px;
    line-height:50px;
    float:left;
}
.content{
    margin:0px 0px 0px 230px;
}
.container{
    border:1px solid red;
}
.container::after{
    clear:both;
    content:"";
    display:block;
    height:0;
    width:0;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="container">
 <div class="nav">Xalsdk fjaskldfj alskdfj asädf<br>asdf<br>asdf</div>
 <div class="content">
  <h1>Home</h1>
  <p>Bla bla.</p>
 </div>
</div>
</body>
```

- [More information on `clear`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clear)
- [More information on pseudo elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements)